# How can I return the database column name in the results grid when using SQL Server 2008 R2?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a query that returns all the columns from a several tables in a table however would like to identify which column names belong to which table. Is there a way I could have these return on the results grid?

Comment: Be good to know why it deserved a negative vote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you just use:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
```

That should give you the following:

```
TABLE_CATALOG ,
        TABLE_SCHEMA ,
        TABLE_NAME ,
        COLUMN_NAME ,
        ORDINAL_POSITION ,
        COLUMN_DEFAULT ,
        IS_NULLABLE ,
        DATA_TYPE ,
        CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH ,
        CHARACTER_OCTET_LENGTH ,
        NUMERIC_PRECISION ,
        NUMERIC_PRECISION_RADIX ,
        NUMERIC_SCALE ,
        DATETIME_PRECISION ,
        CHARACTER_SET_CATALOG ,
        CHARACTER_SET_SCHEMA ,
        CHARACTER_SET_NAME ,
        COLLATION_CATALOG ,
        COLLATION_SCHEMA ,
        COLLATION_NAME ,
        DOMAIN_CATALOG ,
        DOMAIN_SCHEMA ,
        DOMAIN_NAME
```

Comment: Why do you leave a blank between FROM and INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMN?

Comment: No reason, just copied and pasted from a script I use.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT table_name=sysobjects.name,
       column_name=syscolumns.name,
       datatype=systypes.name,
       length=syscolumns.length

  FROM sysobjects 

  JOIN syscolumns ON sysobjects.id = syscolumns.id

  JOIN systypes ON syscolumns.xtype=systypes.xtype

  WHERE sysobjects.xtype='U'

  ORDER BY sysobjects.name,syscolumns.colid
```

Do you need more information?

Comment: As of SQL Server 2005, you should *not* use the `sysobjects` views anymore - you should use the catalog views in the `sys` schema - `sys.tables`, `sys.columns` and so forth

Comment: @Kamil - Sorry. Am new at this. Do I simply replace sysobjects, etc with the relevant table name, etc?

Comment: No. sysobjects is system table which stores table data and syscolumns - column data, including table and column names. But looks like my brain need update, because that method of getting that data is outdated and not recommended in SQL Server 2008.

Comment: Did you executed that SQL? That returns all what you need.

Comment: @Kamil - Yes that does. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS view:

```
SELECT * 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE 
    TABLE_CATALOG='your database name' AND 
    TABLE_NAME='your table name'
```

Comment: @Radke - I get the error Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
The multi-part identifier "KUpdate" could not be bound.